# Having problems with concurrency and outputobjectstream (java)

Tags: java, multithreading, serialization, concurrency, timer

So, I have a university project in java in which I'm making a bomberman game that should be run on a server. I'm having problems because of some timers that are creating new threads that are changing the object Map while I'm trying to send it.

I tried to use the synchronize(Map) on the code blocks of the timers and the outputstream but didn't work

I also have a problem where I want to keep my class Image_Library as a transient because it doesn't need to be sent over the stream, but when I mark the ArrayLists inside as such they're just considered null instead.

Here's some code:

```
public class GameHandler extends Thread{
    private ArrayList<Client> Players = new ArrayList<Client>();
    private ArrayList<Bomber> Characters = new ArrayList<Bomber>();
    public GameLogic L;
    transient private Image_Library lib;
    private Map m;
    private ArrayList<Integer> Actions = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    GameHandler(Client x1, Client x2) {
        x1.AddToGame(this);
        x2.AddToGame(this);
        Players.add(x1);
        Players.add(x2);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean init=true;

        for(int i=0;i<Players.size();i++) {
            Create_New_Socket(Players.get(i));
        }

        Timer tt = new Timer();
        tt.schedule(new Player_Info_Query(),0,200);

        while(true) {
            if(!init){
            }
            else {
                int i;
                for(i=0;i<Players.size();i++) 
                    if(Players.get(i).GetBomber()==null)
                        break;
                if(i==Players.size()) {
                    init=false;
                    tt.cancel();

                    try {
                        init_game();
                        for(i=0;i<Players.size();i++) {
                            Players.get(i).dos.writeUTF("game_start");
                        }
                        Timer tt2 = new Timer();
                        tt2.schedule(new Update_Task(),100);
                    } catch (SlickException | IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private class Player_Info_Query extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {

            for(int i=0;i<Players.size();i++) {
                if(Players.get(i).GetBomber()!=null)
                    continue;
                    try {
                        Players.get(i).Request_Client_Player();
                    } catch (IOException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
            }

        }
    }

    private class Update_Task extends TimerTask{

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
                while(Actions.size()!=0) {
                    L.Action(Actions.get(0));
                    Actions.remove(0);
                }

                lib.Run_Changes();
            } catch (SlickException e1) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
            for(int i=0;i<Players.size();i++)
                try {

                        Players.get(i).Send_Map(m);

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            Timer tt2 = new Timer();
            tt2.schedule(new Update_Task(),100);
        }

    }

    private void Create_New_Socket(Client x){
        try {
            x.objectsocket = new Socket(x.datasocket.getInetAddress(),x.outputsocket);
            System.out.println("SOCKET CREATED " + x.objectsocket);
            x.oos = new ObjectOutputStream(x.objectsocket.getOutputStream());
            x.ois = new ObjectInputStream(x.objectsocket.getInputStream());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        // obtaining input and out streams
    }

    private void init_game() throws SlickException {
        lib = new Image_Library();
        Layout_Logic map_gen = new Layout_Logic(lib);
        m = map_gen.Generate_Standard_Map();
        L=new GameLogic(lib,m);
        Characters = new ArrayList<Bomber>();
        for(int i=0;i<Players.size();i++){
            Characters.add(Players.get(i).GetBomber());
        }

        L.Place_Characters(Characters);
    }

    public void Buffer_Input(int key){
        Actions.add(key);
    }
} 
package GameLogic;
import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

public class Image_Library implements Serializable{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -8459759623730666317L;
    private ArrayList<Element> Flagged = new ArrayList<Element>();
    private ArrayList<String>  Flagged_images = new ArrayList<String>();
    public Map m;

    public void Flag_For_Change(Element x,String img){
            Flagged.add(x);
            Flagged_images.add(img);
    }

    public void Run_Changes() throws SlickException {
        while(Flagged.size()!=0 && Flagged_images.size()!=0) {

            Flagged.get(0).Set_Image(Flagged_images.get(0));
            Flagged.remove(0);
            Flagged_images.remove(0);
        }
    }
} 
package GameLogic;
import org.newdawn.slick.SlickException;

import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;


public class Bomber extends Element{
    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -9085303141098935687L;
    transient protected boolean bomb_cd;
    transient protected boolean Walking_cd;
    static private int cooldown = 500; //milliseconds
    static private int bomb_cooldown=1000;
    static protected int move_res = 5;
    protected int progression_count=move_res;
    protected int direction;    //0-down 1-left 2-up 3-right
    static protected String StopDown="StopDown";
    static protected String Down1="Down1";
    static protected String Down2="Down2";
    static protected String StopUp="StopUp";
    static protected String Up1="Up1";
    static protected String Up2="Up2";
    static protected String StopLeft="StopLeft";
    static protected String Left1="Left1";
    static protected String Left2="Left2";
    static protected String StopRight="StopRight";
    static protected String Right1="Right1";
    static protected String Right2="Right2";
    protected int upkey,downkey,rightkey,leftkey,actionkey;
    private int player;


    public Bomber(int x,int y,Image_Library lib,Map m,int c1,int c2,int k1,int k2, int k3, int k4,int k5,int p) throws SlickException{
        Coordinate tmp = new Coordinate(x,y);
        Coord=tmp;
        Solid=true;
        this.lib=lib;
        this.m=m;

        img=StopDown;

        upkey=k1;
        downkey=k2;
        leftkey=k3;
        rightkey=k4;
        actionkey=k5;
        player=p;
        img = StopDown;
        bomb_cd=false;
        Walking_cd=false;
        //direction=0;
        GUI_Scale=64;
    }

    public void MoveUp() {
        Coord.MoveUp();
        direction=2;
        Start_Walking();    
    }

    public void MoveRight() {
        Coord.MoveRight();
        direction=3;
        Start_Walking();
    }

    public void MoveLeft() {
        Coord.MoveLeft();
        direction=1;
        Start_Walking();
    }

    public void MoveDown() {
        Coord.MoveDown();
        direction=0;
        Start_Walking();
    }

    private void Start_Walking(){
        Walking_cd=true;
        Timer tt = new Timer();
        tt.schedule(new Walking(this),0,cooldown/move_res);
        progression_count=0;
    }

    public void Used_Bomb(){
        bomb_cd=true;
        Timer tt = new Timer();
        tt.schedule(new Bomb_Cd(), bomb_cooldown);
    }

    public boolean Can_Use_Bomb(){
        return !bomb_cd;
    }

    public boolean Can_Walk() {
        return !Walking_cd;
    }

    public boolean Death_Check(){
        return m.Has_Explosion(Coord.getX(),Coord.getY());
    }

    private class Bomb_Cd extends TimerTask{

        public void run(){
            synchronized(m) {
                bomb_cd=false;
            }
        }
    }

    private class Walking extends TimerTask{
        transient private boolean feet=false;
        private Bomber person;
        Walking (Bomber person){
            this.person=person;
            bomb_cd=true;
        }

        public void run(){
                progression_count++;

                if(feet) {
                    if(direction==0)
                        lib.Flag_For_Change(person,Down1);
                    if(direction==1)
                        lib.Flag_For_Change(person,Left1);
                    if(direction==2)
                        lib.Flag_For_Change(person,Up1);
                    if(direction==3)
                        lib.Flag_For_Change(person,Right1);
                }
                else {
                    if(direction==0)
                        lib.Flag_For_Change(person,Down2);
                    if(direction==1)
                        lib.Flag_For_Change(person,Left2);
                    if(direction==2)
                        lib.Flag_For_Change(person,Up2);
                    if(direction==3)
                        lib.Flag_For_Change(person,Right2);
                }

                feet=!feet;

                if(progression_count==move_res){
                    Walking_cd=false;
                    if(direction==0)
                        lib.Flag_For_Change(person,StopDown);
                    if(direction==1)
                        lib.Flag_For_Change(person,StopLeft);
                    if(direction==2)
                        lib.Flag_For_Change(person,StopUp);
                    if(direction==3)
                        lib.Flag_For_Change(person,StopRight);
                    bomb_cd=false;
                    this.cancel();
                }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I strongly recommend adhering to the standard naming conventions. Even if you don't follow it, be consistent, i.e. don't use uppercase and lowercase letters randomly. Further, you didn't show the code doing the serialization, but still, I guess, you're not using it correctly for this task (this assumption is derived from the fact that you are using it at all). Object serialization is not the right tool for this job, as it requires more care than developing a dedicated network protocol for you game.

Comment: I just send the object i want through serialization, the function send map just calls` socket.objectoutputstream(m)`. What would you recommend instead if I want to send an object like this?

Comment: You shouldn't "send an object like this". You should think about the actual data you want to send and only send those. Serialization does lots of things outside you control. First, it remembers every encountered object and transfers only a back-reference when encountering it again. This implies that sending the same object again, to accommodate changed data doesn't work this way (unless you know about the details of flushing internal state or writing an object unshared). It also implies that these remembered objects can create a huge memory leak when not being dropped from time to time.

Comment: Besides that, I doubt that the code looks like `socket.objectoutputstream(m)`. Not even remotely. Further, I see you're initializing a stream and storing it in `oos`, but at another place you're calling `Players.get(i).dos.writeUTF("game_start");`. What is `dos`? Another socket? Or are you writing into the same socket using different streams?

Comment: I have 2 sockets yes, 1 for control messages 1 for game data and each has input and output stream. The sending part really is `oos.reset()` and then `oos.writeObject(x)`. I guess I can send the individual map info 1 by 1 and then send a new message like game_update_done when everything has been sent.

Comment: I can only recommend to keep it simple. Lots of threads and timers and multiple sockets for player are not really needed and make the whole program unmaintainable. More help is not possible on Stackoverflow for a software of this magnitude...